# Cannot open file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble with opening files, python (2.7) tells me that there is no such file, but there is.

```
        csvData = None
        csvHeader = None
        os.chdir("../result/files/")
        for fileName in os.listdir("."):
            if fileName.endswith(".csv"):
                print fileName
                with open("../result/files/"+fileName, 'rb') as csvFile:
                    readerCsv = reader(csvFile, delimiter = ';')
                    csvHeader = readerCsv.next()
                    _unused = readerCsv.next()
                    self.data = list.append(list(readerCsv))
```

this code is suposed to read 5 csv files and store their content in data (except for the first line)

At first chdir tells me he found Stats20120903.csv then I ask the program to open said file but I get an error :

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../files/Stats20120903.csv'
```

why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.chdir`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=chdir#os.chdir) does not tell you what is in the directory, it changes the current working path. All relative file path you give are relative to the working dir.

You should either

- remove the `os.chdir("../result/files/")` and call os.listdir("../result/files/") or
- not add `"../result/files/"` to the filename you want to open.

Comment: removing os.chdir("../result/files/") and replacing "." by "../result/files/" worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
with open(fileName, 'rb') as csvFile:
```

instead of looking relative to the directory you've changed to.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `os.path.abspath()` to find out what actual path Python is trying to use.